# Selecting an image from the gallery and storing its URI into a database

Tags: android, android-intent, android-sqlite, android-permissions, android-gallery

I Want to select a image from the gallery and save its URI to a database and then later retrieve it in another activity of the same project.

I used ACTION_PICK intent and in OnActivityResult, i got the URI of the image using intent.getData(). I saved this URI to the SQLite database.( As a string)

Later, when retrieving it from the database, i get an error that says :

Permission Denial:opening provider    com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider.impl.MediaContentProvider from ProcessRecord

What could be the problem?

Comment: store image path instead on imageURI

Comment: any specific reason or theory for doing so ? @MilanPansuriya

Comment: it will take low storage in SQLite

Comment: Tried it, now the error says :
Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Comment: are you store the complete path of the image ?

Comment: Please show code for the used intent. And code where you try to open the image after the database. Start with telling us full content scheme. `( As a string)`. Which string exactly?

Comment: `Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException:` You cannot use the File class for an uri obtained with ACTION_PICK. You better show your code. You lett us guess now what you are doing.

Comment: Got it, i used EXTERNAL_WRITE_PERMISSION which worked fine and solved the file not found exception.